# No null safety on variable re-assignment?

Tags: kotlin

In my android project I have overriden `onCheckedChanged()` like so:

```
var numberOfPlayers: Int = 0

override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checked: Int) {
    val chosen = activity?.findViewById<RadioButton>(checked)?.text
    numberOfPlayers = chosen.toString().toInt()
}
```

And I'm confused why `numberOfPlayers` isn't underlined red as `chosen` may be `null` - therefore I'm calling `toString()` on a possible `null` value. Why won't this cause a  `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 8):

`.toString()` has a safety, meaning if it receives  a `null` value it will return "null" string.

As [stated in the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html):

> `fun Any?.toString(): String`
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. Can be called with a
>   null receiver, in which case it returns the string "null"

Answer (score 1):

Normal `toString()` from `kotlin.Any` should throw exception if value is null. But, there is also method `Any?.toString()` from `kotlin.kotlin_builtins`.

As `kotlin.Any.toString` cannot be applied to nullable type your compiler knows what method should use.

See this example:

```
fun test() {
    val possibleNull: Any? = Any()
    val notNull: Any = Any()

    possibleNull.toString()

    possibleNull?.toString()
    possibleNull!!.toString()
    notNull.toString()
}
```

If you write this in IntelliJ you'll see that the first `toString()` is actually extenstion method, because that one can be applied to that type. All others examples will call "normal" toString() which would work as you told.

[image]